# Firebase Cloud Messaging works only from localhost

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, localhost, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented the Firebase Cloud Messaging - Push Notifications to my spring-boot web application. Everything works fine, until I needed to deploy my application to a web server or run it from another domain in my network. Even when I try to open :port instead of localhost:8080, the firebase-messaging is not recognized..

I receive the following error messages in the console:

> {code: "messaging/unsupported-browser", message: "Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's …he firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser).", stack: "FirebaseError: Messaging: This browser doesn't sup…  at http://192.168.1.3:8080/js/FireBase.js:14:28"}code: "messaging/unsupported-browser"message: "FirebaseError: Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser).↵    at Object.messaging (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.7.0/firebase-messaging.js:1:35551)

Uncaught ReferenceError: messaging is not defined..

FireBase.js line 14 is:

```
// Retrieve the FireBase Messaging object.
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

I am searching the whole day about it, but I couldn't find any adequate solution..

I would be very thankful to any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some instances that you need to check. 
First, make sure your browser is up to date.
Second, test Firebase without any extensions on your browser especially on Chrome.
Third, When going online, Prefer HTTPS instead of HTTP. So it comes with the SSL related issue.

Please see the code that checks if the browser has the necessary APIs  [firebase-js-sdk-](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/0beb028de38c74198592f47618400f9905d605da/packages/messaging/index.ts#L86)

PS: To test it immediately, just insert your code inside Try/Catch.

[edit]: If you don't want to make a try/catch statement, please consider [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.messaging#.isSupported)

Comment: thank you for your answer. My browser is up to data(on MacOS). I don't have any extensions on Chome. I am not going online, event accessing the app from my machine(localhost) when typing my ip and port, it shows this error. It only works when I open localhost.. I inserted the code in a Try/Catch and I receive exception with the same error...

Comment: I am trying to enable the HTTPS with a self-signed sertificate. The problem is the SSL. Firebase does not work with HTTP.. 
Now there is a problem with the HTTPS. Tried almost everything, did it from the tutorial https://www.thomasvitale.com/https-spring-boot-ssl-certificate/ ..

Error message:
An SSL certificate error occurred when fetching the script.
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Comment: Since you've figured out the problem is the HTTPS, then you can consider this solution [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/854)

Comment: Thank you! Definetely the problem is in the SSL Certificate, because I am using a self-signed Certificate. I read the suggestions in that link, but I was not able to fix it.. where should I place this Certificate? Could this actually work with that kind of certificate..

Comment: You should use valid certificate, you should buy or if it's not a wildcard you can use let's encrypt for free. https://letsencrypt.org/